# How to say: I want to be good at what I choose to do

Tags: grammar

How to say: I want to be good at what I choose to do?

I know some of the individual words/expressions needed for the sentence: 
1)want to be good at: 得意になりたい or 上手になりたい
2)choose to do something: なになにを決める

But how would one say this structure in Japanese: things I choose to do?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use a relative clause to modify the "thing(s)" ("こと").  In case you did not know, the noun 「こと」 is placed ***after*** the relative clause in Japanese, which is the exact opposite of English.

English: "**the things** that I choose to do"

Japanese: 「自分{じぶん}がすると決{き}めた**こと**」

This big difference in word order must be the reason that we receive so many questions about relative clause with the questioners not even seeming to know they are asking about relative clause.

Thus, the natural-sounding ways to say what you wanted to say would include:

・「自分が（やる or する）と決めたことが上手{じょうず}になりたい。」

・「自分が（やりたい or したい）と決めたことがうまくなりたい。」

・「（やる or する）と決めたことが得意{とくい}になりたい。」

It would sound **less** natural if you used a first-person pronoun like 「わたし/ボク, etc.」.  We would use either 「自分」 or nothing at all.  Your listener/reader will know exactly who you are talking about.